# Flexbox responsive layout alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Having some troubles getting a layout correctly responsive using Flexbox.

Imagine a page only containing some panels. The **goal** is to show an x-amount of panels / row, aligned horizontal & vertical as the other ones.

The **problem** I am currently facing is the alignment when a panel switches from row. Trying to align a panel straight underneath the above one, but this is not working out at all.

My results so far:

**Desktop**

[image]

**Tablet** *(here you'll see the problem in alignment (I should be right underneath the top left one...))*

[image]

**Phone**

[image]

**Code** *(simplified)*

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

-

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  justify-content: space-around;

  .item {
    margin-top: 24px;
    width: 264px;
    height: 183px;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `justify-content: space-between;` instead of `space-around` for `.container`

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me out here. I can work with it!